# How to create a custom UIButton with same Buttonsystemitem click effect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a custom button item for my navigation bar, and I want it to have the same effect as the button system item ( Slow fade out ) 
Here is my code :

```
var button_user : UIImage = UIImage(named:"user.png")!

        let button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton

        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "user.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "user_clicked.png"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        button.addTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 30)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: what is the system click effect

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. But one answer to you question is that :22×22 points for the size of bar button

Comment: I just want to have the same highlight on click as any UIbutton

Comment: Hey @YasserB. try this : someButton.setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted(true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `UIButtonType.Custom` to `UIButtonType.System` for that:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)

button.setImage(UIImage(named: "user.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "user_clicked.png"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
button.addTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 30)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

**Edit**

Updated for Swift 2.0

Comment: Great answer, really worked! Improvement suggestion: assuming the button will have the same dimensions as the images, you could do this for instance: `let imgNormal = UIImage(named: "user.png"); [...] button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgNormal.size.width, imgNormal.size.height)`

Comment: Also, for Swift 2, `UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System)` is now a [convenience init](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType:): `UIButton(type: .System)`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You should use `UIBarButtonItem` instead of `UIButton` in the navigation  bar. That will do.

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backbutton"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "buttonClicked:")
```

And also add the method

```
func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject){
    //Enter your code here
}
```

add more "images" for the `UIControlState` accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm having a better highlight effect, but i'm not able to have the same as the system items. see edited post

Comment: @YasserB. Cannot access the file.

Comment: Yes so you don't have any idea how to make the same Highlight effect ?

Comment: I just want the same slow fade out

Comment: @YasserB. You need to add a little animation to the button. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178531/how-fade-in-uibutton

Comment: Thanks ! but do you have any Idea how to make that in swift

Comment: @YasserB. It's almost the same, just a little different in syntax.

Comment: I don't know objective C, I've just started developing with Swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87277/discussion-between-roger-and-yasser-b).

Comment: @YasserB. You should use UIBarButtonItem instead of UIButton in the navigation bar

Comment: @YasserB. If this reply solved your problem. You can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        if isHighLighted == false{
            sender.highlighted = true;
            isHighLighted = true
        }else{
            sender.highlighted = false;
            isHighLighted = false
        }
     });
}
```

OR

```
button.setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted(true)
```